# Numpy: combine two arrays into a matrix, and then map with a lambda

Tags: python, numpy

I want to combine two `numpy.ndarray` with `(m, n)` elements into a `m x n` matrix, and then apply a function/lambda for mapping values.

For example:

```py
import numpy as np
X = np.array([1,2,3])
Y = np.array([4,5,6,7])
Z = cross_combine(X, Y)
# combine two arrays into a matrix containing the tuple (Xi, Yj)
# array([[(1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (1,7)],
#        [(2,4), (2,5), (2,6), (2,7)],
#        [(3,4), (3,5), (3,6), (3,7)]])

Z = Z.map(lambda x, y: x * y)
# map values with a lambda or a function
# array([[4, 5, 6, 7],
#        [8, 10, 12, 14],
#        [12, 15, 18, 21]])
```

The mapping function would be complex. What are the `cross_combine` and `map` functions in numpy? How can I achieve that easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your particular example, you could use [np.meshgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) and [reduce](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html):

```
import numpy as np


def mesh(values):
    return np.array(np.meshgrid(*values)).T

X = [1,2,3]
Y = [4,5,6,7]

Z = mesh([X, Y])

result = np.multiply.reduce(Z, axis=2)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8 10 12 14]
 [12 15 18 21]]
```

For a custom function you could use [np.frompyfunc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html):

```
def_mult = np.frompyfunc(lambda x, y: x * y, 2, 1)
result = def_mult.reduce(Z, axis=2)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[4 5 6 7]
 [8 10 12 14]
 [12 15 18 21]]
```

Comment: How can I use a custom function, not just multiply?

Comment: @李岡諭 Updated the answer!

Comment: You could let the `def_mult` use broadcasting and skip the `meshgrid` step: `def_mult(np.array(X)[:,None], Y)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehensions:

```
X = [1,2,3]
Y = [4,5,6,7]
```

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) in a list comprehension to get the cartesian product of the two lists, preserving the specified nested list structure:

```
Z = [list(product([x],Y)) for x in X]
#[[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7)],
# [(2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7)],
# [(3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7)]]
```

And use a nested list comprehesion to apply a function preserving the structure:

```
[[x*y for x,y in z] for z in Z]
#[[4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 10, 12, 14], [12, 15, 18, 21]]
```

Comment: I strongly recommend **not** using lists, and especially not list comprehensions, if the data is available in arrays!

Comment: Thanks. How's the performance compared with np.array? Is that still suitable for large data?

Comment: Originally it was not available as arrays, that's why I suggested a solution using list comprehensions. @李岡諭 numpy will definitely be faster

Comment: `numpy` will not be faster if you have to call your custom function with scalar `x,y` values.  `numpy` is faster if the function uses compiled whole-array computations like multiply.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that operation like this:

```
import numpy as np

X = [1, 2, 3]
Y = [4, 5, 6, 7]
Z = np.tensordot(X, Y, axes=0)
print(Z)
# [[ 4  5  6  7]
#  [ 8 10 12 14]
#  [12 15 18 21]]
```

For other operations, you can do something like:

```
import numpy as np

X = [1, 2, 3]
Y = [4, 5, 6, 7]
X2d = np.asarray(X)[:, np.newaxis]
Y2d = np.asarray(Y)[np.newaxis, :]

print(X2d * Y2d)
# [[ 4  5  6  7]
#  [ 8 10 12 14]
#  [12 15 18 21]]
print(X2d + Y2d)
# [[ 5  6  7  8]
#  [ 6  7  8  9]
#  [ 7  8  9 10]]
print(X2d ** Y2d)
# [[   1    1    1    1]
#  [  16   32   64  128]
#  [  81  243  729 2187]]
```

EDIT: Or actually just with:

```
import numpy as np

X = [1, 2, 3]
Y = [4, 5, 6, 7]

print(np.multiply.outer(X, Y))
# [[ 4  5  6  7]
#  [ 8 10 12 14]
#  [12 15 18 21]]
print(np.add.outer(X, Y))
# [[ 5  6  7  8]
#  [ 6  7  8  9]
#  [ 7  8  9 10]]
print(np.power.outer(X, Y))
# [[   1    1    1    1]
#  [  16   32   64  128]
#  [  81  243  729 2187]]
```

Comment: I have a complex function for mapping, how can I apply that function?

Comment: @李岡諭 In order for this to work, your function should be vectorized (which is the recommended way to work with NumPy); if it is, it should work with `X2d` and `Y2d`. If you could show what your actual function looks like (even if it is just something similar to it) it may be easier to tell (`lambda x, y:  x * y` obviously works).